# How to read headers data in hub SignalR ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, header, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm trying to pass **userId** to hub on connection to signalR. This is how client sets up the connection:

```
         connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("http://localhost:56587/hub", options =>
            {
                options.Headers["UserId"] = loginTextBox.Text;
            })
            .AddMessagePackProtocol()
            .Build();
```

How can I read this header in OnConnectedAsync() method in my hub?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**To get Header Value as string:**

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    var httpCtx = Context.GetHttpContext();
    var someHeaderValue = httpCtx.Request.Headers["UserId"].ToString();
}
```

*Note* - You may want to consider passing information in the query string however as not all transports support headers.

Comment: This is no longer possible in SignalR Core 3.0

Comment: No idea,@WolfG. Haven't worked with it in the last three years.